# Jquery: Iterating table. Issue= "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am again back with my question.

I am trying to iterate a table in jquery. My below code works if the table has an id. However if my code is like below it doesn't work.

I am simply trying to target a table, iterate it and find a span with a class 'price' which has text 'eight' in it. But I am getting an error 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined' at first for loop.

Here is my code.

```
<html class=" reevoomark_ATY">
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Special Offers</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td><span class="price">one</span></td>
            <td><span class="price">two</span></td>
            <td><span class="price">three</span></td>
            <td><span>X</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>four</span></td>
            <td><span>five</span></td>
            <td><span>six</span></td>
            <td><span>X</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>seven</span></td>
            <td><span class="price">eight</span></td>
            <td><span>nine</span></td>
            <td><span>X</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>ten</span></td>
            <td><span>eleven</span></td>
            <td><span>twelve</span></td>
            <td><span>X</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="dark">
        <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="price">one</span></td>
                    <td><span class="price">two</span></td>
                    <td><span class="price">three</span></td>
                    <td><span class="price">X</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="price">four</span></td>
                    <td><span class="price">five</span></td>
                    <td><span class="price">six</span></td>
                    <td><span class="price">X</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="price">seven</span></td>
                    <td><span class="price">eight</span></td>
                    <td><span class="price">nine</span></td>
                    <td><span class="price">X</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="price">ten</span></td>
                    <td><span class="price">eleven</span></td>
                    <td><span class="price">twelve</span></td>
                    <td><span class="price">X</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var table = $('#dark').find('.table');
            //console.log($(table).attr('class'));
            for (var i = 0, row; row = $(table).rows[i]; i++) {
            for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                var price = $(this).find('.price').text();
                if(price == 'eight'){
                    $(this).find('.price').parent().next().addClass('removeMe');
                }
            }  
            }
        });
    </script>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: `$(table).rows` will be undefined I should think. There is no such property on a jQuery object. Try `table[0].rows`. Rows is a property of the native DOM element object, and `table` is already a jQuery object, without you wrapping it in another one. The `[0]` will return the first DOM element object within the jQuery object, this should be your table.

Comment: Your `for` loop definitions are also faulty - go and look up the correct way to define the second clause - right now they'll probably never execute. I think you want to loop until you get to the value of `length` of the rows collection in the first loop, and the cells collection _within the current row_ in the second one. e.g. `i < table[0].rows.length;` for the first loop, I think. You can figure out the second one from this, hopefully.

Comment: `var price = $(this).find('.price').text();` is also suspect, AFAIK `this` does not have any special meaning with a `for` loop and so will likely refer to the whole document. Try `var price = $(row[i].cells[j]).find(".price").text();` instead, off the top of my head.

Comment: Overall I think you need to study some JavaScript basics a bit more and also consult the documentation more often.

Comment: ADyson, Thanks for explaining each statement with proper explanation. I have never tried many things in jQuery/javascript. I am learning through different examples.

Comment: No problem. There are lots of free online tutorials, courses, videos, books you can buy etc. Just search around for something which suits you

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to iterate anything. just use the jquery selectors and the filter function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('table td .price').filter(function() {
     return $(this).text() == 'eight'
   }).parent().next().addClass('removeMe');
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4s9ve25d/

Comment: Can somebody suggest me a way to practice javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add the class 'removeMe' on the cell after the cell with the text 'eight', so this code will work:

```
$('#dark').find('.table').find('td').each(function()
{
  var price = $(this).find('.price').text();

  if(price == 'eight')
  {
    $(this).next().addClass('removeMe');
  }
});
```

I´ve put on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/charlesartbr/aj9mroyL/5/).

Comment: Charles, Wowww...It's amazing. I really need to work on my basics. How do I be good at it?